# How do I manage arrays of select options in an REACTIVE Angular-form project?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form project, that has form controls and should have form arrays. 
I have done all the preparations but my list of options form  comes out empty.
And also, I can't figure out how to pre-popular both the other select, based on a choice of a previous one. 
(In my head it looks like USA(selected by user) -> Other select turns out to be the list of US states. Happen user to chose some other option, like India -> list of Indian states in another select).

Please help me with this implementation. I can't figure it out by myself, and can't seem to find an appropriate example.

My code is:

Template:

```
    <h2>Basic Details</h2>
<form class="form" [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form__group left">
        <div class="form__control form__first-name">
            <input type="text" name="Fname" required formControlName="">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__email">
            <input type="email" name="email" required formControlName="email">
            <label>Email ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__country" >
            <span>Country</span>
            <select name="country">
                <option *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index" [value]="country" formControlName="country">{{ country }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__phone">
            <input type="number" name="phone" required formControlName="phone">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__button--reset">
            <button type="button" (click)="onReset()">Reset All</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group right">
        <div class="form__control form__last-name">
            <input type="text" name="Lname" required formControlName="lastName">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__ID">
            <input type="text" name="ID" required formControlName="id">
            <label>Your User ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__location">
            <div class="form__location--state">
                <span>State</span>
                <select name="state" formArrayName="state">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form__location--city">
                <span>City</span>
                <select name="city" formArrayName="city">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__code">
            <input type="text" name="code" required formControlName="code">
            <label>Reference Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__control form__button--submit">
            <button type="submit">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS-code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;
  countries = ['USA', 'India'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
      'firstName': new FormControl(null),
      'email': new FormControl(null),
      'formCountries': new FormArray([]),
      'phone': new FormControl(null),
      'lastName': new FormControl(null),
      'id': new FormControl(null),
      'state': new FormArray([]),
      'city': new FormArray([]),
      'code': new FormControl(null)
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it right that you want a `FormArray`? Because `FormArray` means that you have an array of `FormControl`s. If you only want to be able to select multiple for example states from a select change your `FormArray`s to `FormControl`s.

```
let myOptions: {viewValue: string, value: string, disabled: boolean} = [
  {
    viewValue: "Audi",
    value: "Audi",
    disabled: true
  }
];
```

```
<select formControlName="myControlName" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of myOptions" [disabled]="opt.disabled" [value]="opt.value">
    {{opt.viewValue}}
  </option>
</select>
```

```
myCountries: {
  name: string,
  states: {
    name: string,
    cities: {
      name: string,
      postcode: number
    }[]
  }[]
}[] = [
  name: 'USA',
  states: [
    {
      name: 'California',
      cities: [
        {
           name: 'My City',
           postcode: '123456'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Like that:             <div class="form__location--city">
                <span>City</span>
                <select name="city" formControlName="city">
                </select>
            </div>

Comment: I don't understand how to get select options to be displayed? For example here what did I do wrong:         <div class="form__control form__country" >
            <span>Country</span>
            <select name="country">
                <option *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index" [value]="country" formControlName="country">{{ country }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

Comment: An option can't be a `FormControl`. Your `select` is a `FormControl`. To disable an `option` you set the property `disabled`.

Comment: Look at my edits. Instead of the `disabled` attribute of my option you can serve a function which checks if you option is disabled or not.

Comment: Ok, I kinda get what you mean, but I want like an Array of controls that would be looped by ngFor and rendered in a template and from them I want to do a choice that would affect the other select... This is kinda my idea.

Comment: I refactored it using your example. Now it become almost like I imagined, but from the first use my two options are blank and get displayed only after choosing twice a blank field.

Comment: In your case I would suggest to use nested objects instead of different controls.